# Inconsistent digits beyond decimal when combined with scientific notation kableExtra table R markdown html

Tags: r, html-table, markdown, kableextra

My problem comes from having columns that I want to format differently. I would like the same # of digits beyond the decimal point on all column, but on the final column the p-value column I'd like scientific notation to show for the really small numbers. I'd still like to have the same # of digits shown for the scientific notation beyond the decimal. I have tried several combinations of digits, width, and format with nothing giving me the result I am looking for.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

k.table <- mlr_table3 %>%
  mutate(P_value= cell_spec((formatC(x=P_value, digits=3, width = 3, format='g', flag = "-", drop0trailing = TRUE, preserve.width = "common")), "html", color = ifelse(P_value <= 0.05, yes="red", no="blue"), escape = F)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) {
    cell_spec((formatC(x,digits=2, width=3, format="f", flag="-", drop0trailing = FALSE)), "html")
  }) %>%
  kable("html", escape = FALSE, align = "l", caption = "Summarized linear model with SSC Data") %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", "bordered"), full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T)

print.knitr_kable(k.table)
```

Right now the digits in the table looks like this...

`Summarized linear model with SSC Data
term     estimate    std.error   statistic   P_value
(Intercept) 14.93   0.35    43.24   1.06e-173
Cortland    -5.58   1.00    -5.58   3.86e-08
Fire        -4.00   1.68    -2.38   0.0179
Frost       -1.64   1.09    -1.51   0.132
Haral       -5.32   1.09    -4.90   1.28e-06
HoneyA      -4.81   1.11    -4.35   1.63e-05
HoneyB      -0.97   1.09    -0.89   0.373
Sake        -2.12   1.09    -1.95   0.0517
Mac         -1.88   1.14    -1.65   0.1
Sweet       -1.71   1.09    -1.57   0.116`

Answer (score 1):

To remove scientific notation, use `format` and set `scientific = FALSE`

```
> x <- 1e10
> x
[1] 1e+10
> format(x, scientific = FALSE)
[1] "10000000000"
```

To fix number of decimal digits, use `round` and set `digits` value

```
> x <- 0.0167
> round(x, digits = 2)
[1] 0.02
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using my `huxtable` package:

```
library(broom)
library(huxtable)

# example data frame:
tbl <- tidy(lm(mpg ~ gear + cyl, data = mtcars)) 
ht  <- as_hux(tbl)

# 3 decimal places for columns 2-4:
number_format(ht)[, 2:4] <- 3  

# 4 significant figures, and possible scientific notation, for the p values:
number_format(ht)[, 5] <- "%.4g"

ht
##  (Intercept)   34.659   4.937   7.020    1.014e-07  
##  gear          0.652    0.904   0.721    4.766e-01  
##  cyl           -2.743   0.373   -7.344   4.324e-08  

Column names: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value
```

You can use anything recognized by `?sprintf`, or even define your own arbitrary function, to format numbers. Printing to HTML or PDF is automatic within a Rmarkdown document.